# Capture desktop Screen with javascript

Tags: javascript

Can anyone help me with capture desktop with javascript or any plugin.
I have tried to do with html2canvas but i can't capture whole the screen it will just capture the browser page.

Comment: Check that link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912092/using-html5-canvas-javascript-to-take-screenshots/6678156#6678156 and this one http://www.xpertdeveloper.com/2012/10/webpage-screenshot-with-html5-js/

Comment: You can ask use to go in Full screen mode and then take the screenshot.

Comment: There's an app built with Javascript for the same purpose with electron framework https://getkap.co/ also check https://electron.atom.io

Comment: There are many plugin in chrome and firefox like "awesome screenshot" which capture the whole screen.